# Nativescript: project from online Playground

Tags: nativescript

im a newbie. I downloaded a project from Playground, is this project standard NS+Angular? or just NS core?

Comment: Would be nice if you provide more information about 'the project'. An example or links would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url - if it has play-ng then it is an angular app.